# Python - subclass open?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subclass

Is is possible to subclass python's built-in open?  I am intermittently getting the following error:

```
class Open(open):
    pass

x = mymodule.Open()
```

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances

The

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `open` is not a class, it is a function. However, the `file` object is a type that you can subclass.

```
type(open)
# OUT: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
type(file)
# OUT: <type 'type'>
```

Answer (score 2):

`open` is a function, not a class. You can only subclass classes.